# URL - Rewriting and showing the clients dynamic websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am creating an website that will allow users too create there own blog/Content to there website. and depending upon there keyword their website will be created, same as blogspot.

So how can i redirect/show the client website when anyone enters the url such as http://www.clientid.xyz.com/

where my website will be www.xyz.com.

Moreover i have an shared server, i was not achieve this in shared server, so can i achieve this? and if yes then how can I?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's normally referred to as URL rewriting does not work with domains. It only works with subdirectories and pages within the domain.

You need to be able to modify your domain records. This is not a C# issue, it's a domain control issue. And I seriously doubt you'll have that control on a shared hosting account.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, but can i edit domain records with code and achieve what i have to do?

Comment: Are you able to edit them manually? As I already stated, the first issue is if you have the priviledge/control.

Comment: Note, again, that this has nothing to do with what is called URL rewriting. Here's a Google search to get you started: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23.net+%2BDnsModifyRecordsInSet. But I would be very surprised if you can do this programmatically on a shared server.